# How can I find the geometric median of n points in 2D Euclidean space using high school level calculus and optimization of total distance?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, computational-geometry, second-order-cone-programming

I am a high school student trying to work on a math project. I have plotted the coordinates of all households in a Kenyan village and am trying to locate the geometric median of the set of points to find the ideal point to built a well.

I have tried using Fermat's problem and the smallest enclosing circle problem, but these solutions are too complex for my high school math project. Is there a way to solve this using high school calculus? It could go a little beyond but I can't do things like second-order cone optimization.

The idea is to find an equation for the total distance to the well (unweighted). Take the points (1,2), (1,-1), (-2,-1) so that there are 3 households in the village. I found the distance equation, but realized that there are 2 variables in the equation so I can't do optimization and implicit differentiation.

I don't know what to do! I am already halfway through this project and can't scrap it!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you're allowed to use a computer, you can find some code to calculate geometric median on Stack Overflow, e.g. at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299267/geometric-median-of-multidimensional-points.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth thank you for the help, yes I can find an algorithm but as part of my Math Internal Assessment I have to show proof of problem solving using things we work on in class, so calculus, multivariable, etc. Just using an algorithm would defeat the purpose.

Comment: I don't think there is a closed form expression for the median